# Append elements to multiple keys of a Python dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, append

I am trying to append elements to multiple dictionary keys in a loop. However, right now i see only a long way to do this - separate line for every key update, for example:

```
# My dictionary
my_dict = {'Key1': [0], 'Key2': [0], 'Key3': [0]}

# Show initial state
print(my_dict)

# Populate dictionary with new elements
for i in range(1, 5):
    my_dict['Key1'].append(i)
    my_dict['Key2'].append(-i)
    my_dict['Key3'].append(i^2)

# Show final result
print(my_dict)
```

which gives desired

`{'Key1': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'Key2': [0, -1, -2, -3, -4], 'Key3': [0, 3, 0, 1, 6]}`

However, what i would like to do is to append all these new elements in one line, somehow like this:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    my_dict['Key1', 'Key2', 'Key3'].append(i, -i, i^2)
```

Comment: What is that going to improve?

Comment: @KlausD. Suppose I have not three keys, but a hundred. I wouldn't like writing hundred lines to give new elements to keys. I would like to feed it with just an array or a list in one line.

Comment: If you have a hundred keys, you'd probably use a loop of some sort instead of copy/pasting 100 nearly identical lines. Doing 100 append operations to 100 different keys in a single line would hardly be readable, would it?

Comment: At some point you would have to define the hundreds of keys and their hundreds of expressions anyway.

Comment: @KlausD. well... yes, i would need to define it, but i wouldnt need to repeat the append line  then.

@Aran-Fey, do you mean looping both through dictionary keys and `i` ?

Comment: Pretty much. I'd probably create a dict of functions like `{'Key1': lambda i: i, 'Key2': lambda i: -i, 'Key3': lambda i: i^2}` and loop over that dict.

Comment: the easiest way to append to a dictionary is to use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: You can make `my_dict['Key1', 'Key2', 'Key3'].append(i, -i, i^2)` a valid syntax if you want to though. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a bunch of ways you could approach this, but without getting too fancy, this is the way that first comes to mind.

Note you will have to maintain the ever-expanding list of operations for the keys as they are updated.

```
# My dictionary
my_dict = {'key1': [0], 'key2': [0], 'key3': [0]}

# Show initial state
print(my_dict)

# Populate dictionary with new elements
for i in range(1, 5):
    key_update_operation = {'key1': i, 'key2': -i, 'key3': i^2}
    for k, v in my_dict.items():
        my_dict[k].append(key_update_operation[k])

# Show final result
print(my_dict)
```

This is basically what @Aran-Fey is suggesting, I think. Keep in mind, whilst this example works just fine, readability is a huge thing if you're going to share your code with other people, so don't be scared to just keep it simple, there's not a lot to be gained!

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `dict` and override the `__getitem__` to return an object of a custom class when the argument is a tuple just so that the custom class can have an `append` method to append the corresponding values to the given keys in one shot:

```
class Dict(dict):
    class DictView:
        def __init__(self, d, keys):
            self.d = d
            self.keys = keys

        def append(self, *items):
            for key, item in zip(self.keys, items):
                self.d[key].append(item)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, tuple):
            return self.DictView(self, key)
        return super().__getitem__(key)
```

so that:

```
my_dict = Dict({'Key1': [0], 'Key2': [0], 'Key3': [0]})
for i in range(1, 5):
    my_dict['Key1', 'Key2', 'Key3'].append(i, -i, i^2)
print(my_dict)
```

will output:

```
{'Key1': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'Key2': [0, -1, -2, -3, -4], 'Key3': [0, 3, 0, 1, 6]}
```